# Why does my Laravel policy always return false?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-authorization

The code for the policy is here:

```
class userOwnedClassPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    ...
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return ($user->userType == 'teacher');
    }
    ...
}
```

This policy is registered thusly in the `AuthServiceProvider.php` file:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    //Map models to authorization policies.
    protected $policies = [
        App\Models\classMember::class => App\Policies\classMemberPolicy::class,
        App\Models\evaluation::class => App\Policies\evaluationPolicy::class,
        App\Models\group::class => App\Policies\groupPolicy::class,
        App\Models\groupMember::class => App\Policies\groupMemberPolicy::class,
        App\Models\sharedClass::class => App\Policies\sharedClassPolicy::class,
        App\Models\slg::class => App\Policies\slgPolicy::class,
        App\Models\spreadsheet::class => App\Policies\spreadsheetPolicy::class,
        App\Models\spreadsheetValue::class => App\Policies\spreadsheetValuePolicy::class,
        App\Models\teacher::class => App\Policies\teacherPolicy::class,
        App\Models\test::class => App\Policies\testPolicy::class,
        App\Models\userOwnedClass::class => App\Policies\userOwnedClassPolicy::class
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

(I have tried registering the policies using strings of the file paths as well, but this accomplishes nothing.)

The relevant section of controller code is here:

```
class ClassController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function store(Request $postReq)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', Auth::user());
        userOwnedClass::create([
            'name' => $postReq->input('className'),
            'ownerId' => Auth::user()->id
        ]);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have tried substituting the code in the policy's `create` method with `return true`, but even that fails. What have I done wrong, and why does the controller always return a 403 error when called?

Comment: Try `$this->authorize('create', userOwnedClass::class);`

Comment: That works, but can you explain why? Why do I need to pass the `userOwnedClass` class when I'm not using it in the policy, and why don't I need to pass the `Auth::user()` object, which I do use in the policy?

Comment: The authorization system needs to know what type of object (resource) you are checking authorization against, that is how it knows when to use a Policy, by the type of argument or the class name passed

Comment: So, how would I pass the arguments to the authorization method?

Comment: exactly as IGP said to, your policy method doesn't take an argument for the resource because it isn't defined to so it only takes the class name; that way it can match it up to the policy, this is in the documentation  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#controller-actions-that-dont-require-models

Comment: `$this->authorize('create', userOwnedClass::class)` will use the `create(User $user)` method in the policy class associated with `userOwnedClass:class` according to the array defined in `AuthServiceProvider`, passing `Auth::user()` as the first param implicitly. `$this->authorize('edit', $userOwnedClassInstance)` would use the `edit(User $user, userOwnedClass $userOwnedClass)` method. The answer below explains it.

Answer (score 0):

As you created policy `userOwnedClassPolicy` and set it for `userOwnedClass` model in `AuthServiceProvider` here:

```
App\Models\userOwnedClass::class => App\Policies\userOwnedClassPolicy::class
```

you cannot just run policy method:

```
$this->authorize('create', Auth::user());
```

When you run this line above, you tell - check `create` method for policy for `\App\Models\User` object, but you don't have any policy created for this model.

So in this case you should run it like so:

```
$this->authorize('create', \App\Models\userOwnedClass::class);
```

Then Laravel will know that it should run `create` method from `userOwnedClassPolicy` policy and it will automatically pass currently authenticated user into `$user` variable in policy method.